# Python Timeseries Conditional Calculations Summarized by Month

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have the timeseries dataframe as:

| timestamp | signal_value |
| --- | --- |
| 2017-08-28 00:00:00 | 10 |
| 2017-08-28 00:05:00 | 3 |
| 2017-08-28 00:10:00 | 5 |
| 2017-08-28 00:15:00 | 5 |

I am trying to get the average Monthly percentage of the time where "signal_value" is greater than 5. Something like:

| Month | metric |
| --- | --- |
| January | 16% |
| February | 2% |
| March | 8% |
| April | 10% |

I tried the following code which gives the result for the whole dataset but how can I summarize it per each month?

```
total,count = 0, 0

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    total += 1
    if row["signal_value"] >= 5:
        count += 1
print((count/total)*100)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can help to answer you question while not reproducing your code from scratch. It will help to get an answer much faster. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let us first generate some random data (generate random dates taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50165501/generate-random-list-of-timestamps-in-python/50165755)):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

def randomtimes(start, end, n):
    frmt = '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S'
    stime = datetime.datetime.strptime(start, frmt)
    etime = datetime.datetime.strptime(end, frmt)
    td = etime - stime
    dtimes = [np.random.random() * td + stime for _ in range(n)] 
    return [d.strftime(frmt) for d in dtimes]

# Recreat some fake data
timestamp = randomtimes("01-01-2021 00:00:00", "01-01-2023 00:00:00", 10000)
signal_value = np.random.random(len(timestamp)) * 10
df = pd.DataFrame({"timestamp": timestamp, "signal_value": signal_value})
```

Now we can transform the timestamp column to pandas timestamps to extract month and year per timestamp:

```
df.timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp)
df["month"] = df.timestamp.dt.month
df["year"] = df.timestamp.dt.year
```

We generate a boolean column whether `signal_value` is larger than some threshold (here 5):

```
df["is_larger5"] = df.signal_value > 5
```

Finally, we can get the average for every month by using pandas.groupby:

```
>>> df.groupby(["year", "month"])['is_larger5'].mean()
year  month
2021  1        0.509615
      2        0.488189
      3        0.506024
      4        0.519362
      5        0.498778
      6        0.483709
      7        0.498824
      8        0.460396
      9        0.542918
      10       0.463043
      11       0.492500
      12       0.519789
2022  1        0.481663
      2        0.527778
      3        0.501139
      4        0.527322
      5        0.486936
      6        0.510638
      7        0.483370
      8        0.521253
      9        0.493639
      10       0.495349
      11       0.474886
      12       0.488372
Name: is_larger5, dtype: float64
```